# Passing images from one page to another in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

In  my app I need to pass images from one page to another page image view to display. I am taking a photo from camera and do some stuffs, then I want to send that images to the second page.

```
            if (await isCamAvailable())
            {

                 MediaFile photo1 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions() { Directory = "NewBusiness", Name = "image1.jpg", PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight, MaxWidthHeight = 1024, CompressionQuality = 95 });

                if (photo1 != null)
                {
                    PhotoImage1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo1.GetStream(); });
                    countList.Remove("a");
                    countList.Add("a");
                }

            }
```

Then I am added it to a string array by doing

```
        private List<string> sendImgList = new List<string>();

        sendImgList.Add(createImgByteString(photo1.GetStream()));


        private string createImgByteString(Stream data)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[data.Length];
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
```

Then from second page (for testing i just added only one image)

```
        foreach (string ss in imgList) {

            byte[] Base64Stream = Convert.FromBase64String(ss);
            imgView.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Base64Stream));

        }
```

I followed this example. But image not showing.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/139360/how-to-transfer-images-from-one-page-to-another

Also getting this in logcat..

```
[0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource05-29 14:22:43.758 W/monodroid-assembly( 8737): typemap: unable to find mapping to a Java type from managed type 'System.Byte, mscorlib'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you used the **Media.Plugin** . Why don't you pass the ImageSource directly?
If you do want to convert it to byte array , check the following code

```
public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
{
  var buffer = new byte[16*1024];
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
      return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

```
var imgDate = GetImageStreamAsBytes(photo1.GetStream());
```

It would be better to pass the byte array directly .

Comment: but than how you will get from 2nd page? do i use GetImageStreamAsBytes on 2nd page too?

Answer (score 1):

The best mode to pass parameter in pages is with Prism.

https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/passing-parameters.html

>

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("MainPage", new NavigationParameters
{
    { "key_parameter", image }
})));
```

And on other page:

>

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    image = (Image)parameters["key_parameter"];
}
```